# Is the iOS 13 'Optimized Battery Charging' feature on the iPhone optimised for smart battery cases?

Tags: iphone, battery, charging, case, ios

I have the [iPhone XR Smart Battery Case](https://www.apple.com/uk/shop/product/MU7M2ZM/A/iphone-xr-smart-battery-case-black), I charge my phone every night and therefore my phone very rarely ever goes below 100% charge as it uses the charge in the battery case first.

As I understand it, the idea of the optimised charging feature is to never charge the phone up to 100%, until right before you are expected to use it in the morning.

Assuming I rarely go below 100% charge on the phone, is this feature doing anything at all, and if not, would it make any difference if I were to disable it? (If so, for better, worse or no difference at all)

Comment: Perhaps you are the only one considering this?